# Back button in navigation bar in tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, back

I have a navigation controller that pushes a tab bar controller.
I am trying to hide the back button that appears but I am not successful.

Please help me.

Thank You in advanced

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Note that this has to be in the controller that the back button **goes back to**.

Comment: Again, you should include some context with this answer to explain why it's correct.

Comment: I am able to edit the button with: `self.navigationItem.title = @"";` but when I try `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` it doesn't hide the button. This is all done in the view controller the button goes back to like you said.